# Pull specific IDs from HTML code C#

Tags: c#, html-parsing

I am making a program that you can log into facebook, go to someone's wall and post on it. I have all of this working, if i manually enter in the ID that i go and find in the HTML for the textview box where you write the status and the Post button where you click to post. My problem is that the ID for this textbox and the post button changes every single time you go to the page or the page refreshes. So you cant just code in the ID to get it like this`HtmlElement element = browser.Document.GetElementById("some-ID");` I need to somehow parse the HTML code and pull out the specific IDs for the textview and the button every time the page refreshes. I have looked into html agility pack and it hasn't really helped me any. Can anyone help?

**EDIT**
Here is the line of code I am trying to get the ID out of for the text area where you post. You can see that it is just a random garble of letters and some numbers at the end. It changes every time you load the page. And I haven't looked at the facebook api would it help any?

```
<DIV class="innerWrap"><TEXTAREA aria-expanded="false" onkeydown='Bootloader.loadComponents(["control-textarea"], function() { TextAreaControl.getInstance(this) }.bind(this)); ' id="ujkzdk454" class="DOMControl_placeholder uiTextareaAutogrow input mentionsTextarea textInput" title="Write something..." role="textbox" aria-owns="typeahead_list_ujkzdk453" name="xhpc_message" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="list" placeholder="Write something..." aria-label="Write something...">Write something...</TEXTAREA></DIV></DIV></DIV><INPUT
```

Comment: Please post the code for the element you are trying to find.

Comment: WHy do you want to do this using HTML parsing? Would you not be better off using Facebook API ?

Comment: Yes, I agree... this is something you should be doing with the Facebook API.

Comment: I posted the HTML up of the text area. And I've never done anything with the Facebook API so I'm not sure I really want to get into that. I have the whole program working as long as I go into my file and manually type into a textbox on my form the button ID and textview ID. I just want the program to do this itself.

Comment: Plus if I have to pull IDs from another website ever because of a similar problem with them changing on every page load I would like to know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree you should probably be using the Facebook API but anyway, how about some thing like this with jquery?

```
var textarea = $('textarea', '.innerWrap');
var button = $('.innerWrap').next('input');
```

and if you still want the ids

```
var textareaId = textarea.attr('id')
var buttonId = button.attr('id')
```

Comment: i've never used javascript as i have been taught it is the devil by my one professor haha that's what jquery is based on right? And if there are more than one text areas with the class innerWrap wouldnt this return multiple ids from all of them?

Comment: I'm surprises you say you've never used JavaScript as your original post looks like its using it. Yes, jQuery is built on JavaScript. I'm not sure it would return multiple ids but produce something strange. How about adding a click handler to your button(s) in that case: `$('input', '.innerWrap').click(function(){ var buttonId = $(this).attr('id'); var textAreaId = $(this).prev('textarea').attr('id'); });` That should just get the ids of the button and textarea within the same innerWrap as the clicked button